# Why is it a code smell to add parenthesis on a single argument lambda?

Tags: java

On several websites/analyzers, like Baeldung and SonarQube, I see that wrapping a single argument of a lambda is considered a code smell. Now, I do understand without the parenthesis you'd save two characters, but i.m.h.o it also breaks consistency, looking at the other uses of arguments. To me, consistent use would even increase readability.

```java
a = () -> doSomething();
a = x -> doSomething(x);                // <--- Ok?
a = (x) -> doSomething(x);              // <--- Code smell?
a = (x, y) -> doSomething(x, y);
a = (x, y, z) -> doSomething(x, y, z);
```

Are there other reasons, besides shorter code and personal preference, that parenthesis are considered bad when having one argument?

Comment: I don't know why that's a code smell either, I agree entirely about consistency. But for what it's worth; Baeldung is a site I actively ignore when it comes up in my Google searches. I've found that site/person isn't as knowledgeable as they market themselves to be, or that sometimes incredibly important details are left out, or both. It makes me just steer completely clear of it entirely now.

Answer (score 2):

“Why” questions always invite speculation but I think in this case the reason is fairly obvious: the two extra characters introduce unnecessary *syntactic noise*.

I’m not convinced by your consistency counter-argument, since you presumably also don’t use parentheses around all other expressions where they might appear, right? By the same argument, you’d be forced to write

```
int a = ((1) + (2));
```

instead of

```
int a = 1 + 2;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if comparing an operator is comparable with the more complex lambda structure. With languages like Ruby you can omit parenthesis on function calls, but that's not possible in Java. Code conventions like Google and Twitter Code style advise (more in general) to be liberal on use parenthesis for readability.

Comment: Well your counter-counter doesn't hold up all that well either. That implies that the OP would use parenthesis in some cases where addition takes place.

Comment: @searchengine27 Why yes, and they obviously do, because it’s necessary for operator precedence, e.g. `(a + b) * c`. Of course it’s theoretically possible that OP always distributes across the multiplication to avoid parentheses in arithmetic expression at all cost but I doubt it.

Comment: @Taco Why wouldn’t it be comparable? Both are cases where parentheses around a single syntactic token are optional. “Liberal use” of parentheses around complex expressions is very different from redundant parentheses around individual tokens.

Comment: You're misunderstanding me. I didn't say arithmetic, I said addition. Obviously in some cases it is necessary if you're doing arithmetic. But not for just simple addition. The place where your counter falls apart is more analogous to curly braces rather than addition, however. It is only required to have a statement following parenthesis of an `if` statement. But it is Java standard practice to use the curly brace statement rather than a single line statement followed by a semicolon. It is the exact same scenario as the OP describes for consistency.

Comment: @Taco Incidentally I agree that this is ultimately a judgement call. I espouse the argument I made in my answer but I understand arguing that consistency might be more important. That’s the thing with style guides. They’re often fundamentally a judgement call.

Comment: @searchengine27 But *I* said arithmetic, and this is *my* example: I’m not extrapolating from addition. I’m extrapolating from the general case of arithmetic, which *does* require parentheses, to the simple case of individual terms (which don’t).